# How can I load JSON config file and let the Vue app wait for this?

Tags: vue.js, config, wait, startup

A typical scenario for me is:

- a Vue app (packed with webpack, BTW)
- a separate config file for configuring the app

The config file should *not* be included in the webpacked deployment package, since it is server-dependent (database credentials etc.)

For some reason I am not intending to elaborate on here I keep the config in a JSON file.

So the question is:

How can I **delay** "starting" the Vue app until the JSON config file has been loaded (and parsed) from the backend?

I know how to load and parse, but the question for me is Vue-specific: what's the best practice to "wait" for something before starting the whole thing?

(Is something like `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook in the `App.vue` component the way to go? Does it play nice with asynchronous tasks like loading a JSON file over the net?)

Comment: if your app is written in a way that it won't work with the data being loaded asynchronously then you could simply not call new Vue({ ... until you have loaded your data.

Comment: if you do truly want to delay starting the app. something like @Zaptree said would probably be best. you could load the JSON config in a promise (axios call or maybe reading the file locally) and start the Vue app in the `.then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that I have used to solve this kind of issue is to use the router.beforeEach. Here is an example of my code:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.state.initialized) {
    // the store initialize will set initialized to true
    await store.dispatch('initialize')
  }
  // if user not logged in or the route is not public
  if (!store.state.user && !to.meta.public) {
    next('/login')
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanx for your 2 solutions! I would have accepted the other answer "start Vue in the `.then` of the promise which would pre-load the JSON config file. Since I cannot accept a comment, I accepted this answer instead - which also is cool way to solve this. Which solution is right depends on the use - as you and Shawn pointed out - and in my case with a config, the app is unable to perform its tasks, so I blocked the entire App instead of intercepting each route with `router.beforeEach`.