# Loading vue config at runtime

Tags: vue.js, config

My wish is, that I can build a vue package and install it on any server just by changing the config without recompiling.

My problem:
I don't know how to fetch it.
I use axios for my backend communication at the moment, but I don't know how to download something without knowing the hostname.

I think an ideal solution would be to include a script that contains the config, similar to how the image tag works.
The script should not be minified or included.

But I didn't find a source of anyone doing that (where it worked).

Has anyone a solution for that.

PS: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151184/how-can-i-load-json-config-file-and-let-the-vue-app-wait-for-this), but the hostname problem still remains.

Comment: "changing the config without recompiling" - where does this requirement come from? The point is, if you're able to deploy a script, you're able to deploy an app with .env config. That's why you won't see too many examples of the opposite. Loading a config at runtime isn't specific to Vue at all. Basically fetch .json from public folder and use it to set Axios baseUrl

Comment: I could deploy a .env file this would be perfect, the problem is that is not loaded at runtime. Hat the moment I get the hostname with 'window.location.origin' but I am not sure if this is hack.

Comment: It's loaded to process.env when the app is compiled. Deploying means that the app is compiled. You could want to change anything else without recompiling to, and the result would be the same, this would be against the typical use of Vue setup. You may have XY problem. There's a necessity to know a hostname for websocket (and that's where location.origin is in use), but there's none for HTTP. You could use `/` base url for all requests.

Comment: Just want to add this this shouldn't be so atypical because it's best practice in general not to build config into an application. Typically a build should generate artifacts, and releases should deploy the build artifacts to various environments. This necessitates that config is provided to an artifact after it is built, as the same artifact will be heading to multiple environments.